# How to save custom markers to SQLite Database in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Okay, so I am completely at a loss here!  What I am trying to do is to save the marker (or point) tapped on the map using `onMapLongClick`.  This works but only half way.

What works is the user "Long press" on the map and it then displays the default map marker icon - Great!

What doesn't work is it doesn't save it to the SQLite database - not so great (or it is saving but not displaying when the map loads again ?)

The reason I think it is not loading is that i get the following error `Value must be ≥ 0` by the following lines of code:

```
(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT));
(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG));
(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM));
```

The app surprisingly still runs and works up until the point it needs to save the info to the database :-)

Now for the code:

LocationsDB

```
public class LocationsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static String DBNAME = "locationmarkersqlite";
private static int VERSION = 1;
public static final String FIELD_ROW_ID = "_id";
public static final String FIELD_LAT = "lat";
public static final String FIELD_LNG = "lng";
public static final String FIELD_ZOOM = "zom";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "locations";
private SQLiteDatabase mDB;

public LocationsDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);
    this.mDB = getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql =     "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
            FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
            FIELD_LNG + " double , " +
            FIELD_LAT + " double , " +
            FIELD_ZOOM + " text " +
            " ) ";

    db.execSQL(sql);
}

public long insert(ContentValues contentValues){
    long rowID = mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    return rowID;
}

public int del(){
    int cnt = mDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null , null);
    return cnt;
}

public Cursor getAllLocations(){
    return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { FIELD_ROW_ID,  FIELD_LAT , FIELD_LNG, FIELD_ZOOM } , null, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}
}
```

LocationsContentProvider

```
public class LocationsContentProvider extends ContentProvider{

public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "super.awesome.app.not.working.locations";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/locations" );
private static final int LOCATIONS = 1;

private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;

static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "locations", LOCATIONS);
}

LocationsDB mLocationsDB;
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mLocationsDB = new LocationsDB(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    long rowID = mLocationsDB.insert(values);
    Uri _uri=null;
    if(rowID>0){
        _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
    }else {
        try {
            throw new SQLException("Failed to insert : " + uri);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return _uri;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                  String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int cnt = 0;
    cnt = mLocationsDB.del();
    return cnt;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    if(uriMatcher.match(uri)==LOCATIONS){
        return mLocationsDB.getAllLocations();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
}
}
```

And I have added this to the manifest file:

```
<provider
        android:name="LocationsContentProvider"
        android:authorities="super.awesome.app.not.working.locations"
        android:exported="false" />
```

And where the magic doesn't happen

```
public class InteractiveMapFragment extends Fragment {

MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
private InteractiveMapViewModel InteractiveMapViewModel;
private FragmentInteractivemapBinding binding;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    InteractiveMapViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(InteractiveMapViewModel.class);

    binding = FragmentInteractivemapBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();

    mMapView = (MapView) root.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
            googleMap = mMap;
            LatLng myPoint = new LatLng(-24.9948, 31.5969);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPoint).title("Marker Title").snippet("Marker Description"));

            // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(myPoint).zoom(12).build();
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    drawMarker(latLng);
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    markerOptions.title(latLng.latitude + " : " + latLng.longitude);
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, latLng.latitude );
                    contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG, latLng.longitude);
                    contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM, googleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom);
                    LocationInsertTask insertTask = new LocationInsertTask();

                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }
                class LocationInsertTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Void>
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(ContentValues... contentValues) {

                        /** Setting up values to insert the clicked location into SQLite database */
                        getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, contentValues[0]);
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                class LocationDeleteTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
                    {

                        /** Deleting all the locations stored in SQLite database */
                        getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                private void drawMarker(LatLng latLng){
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(latLng);
                    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }

                public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1)
                {
                    Uri uri = LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI;
                    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, null, null, null, null);

                }
                public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1)
                {
                    int locationCount = 0;
                    double lat=0;
                    double lng=0;
                    float zoom=0;
                    locationCount = arg1.getCount();
                    arg1.moveToFirst();

                    for(int i=0;i<locationCount;i++)
                    {
                        lat = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT));
                        lng = arg1.getDouble(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG));
                        zoom = arg1.getFloat(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM));

                        LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                        drawMarker(location);
                        arg1.moveToNext();
                    }

                    if(locationCount>0)
                    {
                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,lng)));
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom));
                    }
                }

                public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
```

}

In the long run I will add the ability to save images, additional text and all those wonderful things, but at the moment I just need this to save the above to the SQLite database which clearly isn't working. :-(

What am I missing here or doing completely wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Probably you added/modified columns to the table after you first ran the app. Uninstall the app from the device and rerun. If the problem persists try in a clean device.

Comment: Hi @forpas, Thanks.  I have tried that but it is sadly still not working :-(  I have gone through the code again now and it all looks like it should work right?

Comment: The error you get means that 1 or more of the columns LocationsDB.FIELD_??? do not exist.

Comment: But they do exist? I don't understand?

Comment: AndroidStudio comes with a database explorer so I'd use that to inspect schema and entries - post results as well.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I think it is not loading is that i get the following error Value must be ≥ 0 by the following lines of code:

The `Value must be ≥ 0` for using `the_cursor.get???(getColumnIndex("the_column_name"))` is an issue that has been raised. **It is not the cause of the data not being inserted.**

You can supress is using one of

1. `@SupressLint("Range")` *(hover over the error and the option to add the suppression is presented)*
2. Using the `getColumnIndexOrThrow` method instead of the `getColumnIndex` method.
3. Seperating the statements e.g. :-

   ```
   int cursorIndex = csr.getColumnIndex("the_column");
   csr.get???(cursorIndex);
   ```
4. Using SDK 30 instead of SDK 31

The issue has been raised https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/202193843

> The app surprisingly still runs and works up until the point it needs to save the info to the database :-)

Yes, the `Value must be ≥ 0` is only a warning.

**However, the reason that data isn't being saved is because you are creating a LocationInsertTask and apparently doing nothing with it.**

i.e. you have :-

```
    LocationInsertTask insertTask = new LocationInsertTask();
}
```

try using

```
        LocationInsertTask insertTask = new LocationInsertTask();
        insertTask.execute(new ContentValues[]{contentValues});
}
```

- i.e. executing the task.

The underlying `insert` method works i.e. the following code (that bypasses accessing google maps and also the LocationsContentProvider) adds rows to the database :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button doit;
    LocationsDB db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        doit = this.findViewById(R.id.doit);
        db = new LocationsDB(this); // get Database so as to bypass using provider
        //* mimic getting data by using button click
        doit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LAT, 100 ); //<<<<< bypass getting value
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_LNG, 200); //<<<<< bypass getting value
                contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_ZOOM, "zoom"); //<<<<< bypass getting value
                LocationInsertTask insertTask = new LocationInsertTask();
                insertTask.execute(new ContentValues[]{contentValues}); //<<<<<<<<<< FIX >>>>>>>>>>
            }
        });

    }

    class LocationInsertTask extends android.os.AsyncTask<ContentValues, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ContentValues... contentValues) {

            /** Setting up values to insert the clicked location into SQLite database */
            //getContentResolver().insert(LocationsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, contentValues[0]); //<<<<< skip provider
            db.insert(contentValues[0]); 
            return null;
        }
    }

    /*
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    void doNothing() {
        Cursor csr;
        csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex("the_column"));
        csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndexOrThrow("the_column"));
        int cursorIndex = csr.getColumnIndex("the_column");
        csr.getLong(cursorIndex);
    }

     */
}
```

Clicking a few times on the button and :-

[image]

**As such if you have further issues then they will within the `LocationsContentProvider`.**

- Image obtained by using [App Inspection aka Database Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database)